# Facebook Php SDK - Posting a feed using batch is not showing the picture

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-php-sdk

Using the script originally from 25labs.com to post in multiple pages and groups.

It is posting the feed but the pictures are not showing. I'm pretty sure that something is blocking the pictures to show up in the feed, because when i share it in my time line, everything shows up.

I couldn't find anything wrong with the script. Facebook is blocking the images from the feeds. Any idea how to make the pictures to show up?

The form with the information being posted:

Message : A Technology Laboratory..

Link: http://25labs.com

Picture: http://25labs.com/25-labs.jpg

Name: 25 labs

Caption: 25labs.com

Description: Blablabla

Parts of the code:

```
if (!$user) {
    // Get login URL
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope'   => 'publish_stream,user_groups,read_stream,publish_actions,photo_upload,share_item',
            'redirect_uri' => $site_url,
        ));
}

if ($user) {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who has a valid session.
    $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    //========= Batch requests over the Facebook Graph API using the PHP-SDK ========
    // Save your method calls into an array
    $queries = array(
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/groups?limit=5000'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/likes?limit=5000'),
    );

    // POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
    try{
        $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
    }catch(Exception $o) {
        error_log($o);

        foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $id) {
            $batchPost[] = array('method' => 'POST', 'relative_url' => "/$id/feed",'body' => http_build_query($body));

            if ($i++ == 50) {
                try{
                    $multiPostResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');
                    if (is_array($multiPostResponse)) {
                        foreach ($multiPostResponse as $singleResponse) {
                            $temp = json_decode($singleResponse['body'], true);
                            if (isset($temp['id'])) {
                                $splitId = explode("_", $temp['id']);
                                if (!empty($splitId[1])) $list_ids[] = $splitId[0];
                            }elseif (isset($temp['error'])) {
                                error_log(print_r($temp['error'], true));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                    error_log($e);
                }

                $flag=0;
                unset($batchPost);
                $i=1;
            }

        }
```

Comment: So what is the content that you are actually posting? I see you using http_build_query on a variable `$body`, but that is nowhere else to be found in your code.

Comment: its being used in the $batchPost array. and after it is part of the $multiPostResponse.

Comment: I see where it’s being used – but not where you are putting any values into it (and what those are) …

Comment: as i mentioned its the part of the script.... the entire script is too long. all information is coming from the form and its being placed into the array $body.